# How to locate problematic character in .bib file

Tags: bibliographies, biber, input-encodings

I received this message when I try to include my bibliography in the document with `\printbibliography`

```
! Package inputenc Error: Unicode char \u8:‐ not set up for use with LaTeX.

See the inputenc package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.174 ...rintbibliography[heading=subbibliography]
```

I would say the problem is with some character in my .bib file. But if I receive no error message from Biber how do I locate the problematic character?

Comment: At the very least, the `.pdf` or `.dvi` of that subbibliography will likely show some funky characters; and it will probably not be in an entry that contains simple, unaccented characters of the Latin alphabet, but something with accents or from other character sets.

Comment: @jon it is a very long pdf. Is there anyway to add something like `--verbose` to LaTeX and then get the problem?

Comment: It could also be something existent in the bib file, but is not printed to the pdf. Making a miinimal working example will definitely get you to the error, but it might take a while.

Comment: The problematic character is `‐` (U+2010 HYPHEN) as the error states. Simply make a search with your editor for that character in your `.bib` file.

Comment: @karlkoeller That worked.

Comment: Despite the problem being “solved”, how can `inputenc` (probably with `utf8` package option) not support a character as simple and essential as U+2010? My suggestion would be to use `fontspec` instead (with either XeTeX or LuaTeX).

Comment: @karlkoeller Make that an answer, please.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This kind of problem can be easily resolved.

The package `inputenc` shows an error that gives you information about the problematic character in your document. In your case it is `‐` (U+2010 HYPHEN), and the problematic line is `\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography]`, which means that such character is in your `.bib` file.

Using the "search and replace" feature of your editor, substitute that character with one recognised by `inputenc`, e.g. `-` (U+002D HYPHEN-MINUS) and the problem is solved.

A good editor is usually able to show the Unicode code of the character. If yours is not and you want to know that code, you can find lots of tools in the web for this purpose.

An example is [Unicode Character Finder](http://www.mclean.net.nz/ucf/). Paste the character there, and you will get all the needed information on it.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A very similar problem was solved in this question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13596531/how-to-search-for-non-ascii-characters-with-bash-tools

Look at the answer suggesting

```
nonascii() { LANG=C grep --color=always '[^ -~]\+'; }
```

You will be able to see all problematic characters in red and you can add additional grep lines. For example you can ignore UTF-8 in `Author`, but print it in `Pages` fields.